# Case class for value object visibility?

Tags: scala, case-class, companion-object

Is it worth, to control the visibility of case class that represent value object ? If so, is a visibility modifier on the case class enough, or using an explicit companion object, and a private constructor, would be better ?

Version 1:

```
case class MyClass private/protected/private[] {}
```

Version 2:

```
case class MyClass private

object MyClass {

  def apply = {

    new MyClass

  }
}
```

In sum, the question could be summarize as how to deal with value object in scala.
I personally want to enforce the no new, so that is i want to change something in the creation of the object, I can do it at any time. That is, by simply adding a companion object when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>A visibility modifier on the case class constructor does not propagate to the companion object, so creating one yourself by hand with the exact same apply method is unnecessary.</strike>

You can verify this yourself trivially:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class X private () {}
defined class X

scala> new X
<console>:10: error: constructor X in class X cannot be accessed in object $iw
              new X
              ^

scala> X()
res1: X = X()
```

Note that just plain `X` is the name of the companion object.  You can't get a new `X` by naming the companion object; that won't call its apply method even if a no-argument apply exists.  So you can't omit the empty parameter list `()`.

The above is all true in the REPL, but compiled code fails.

Comment: That is the thing, i'm using scala 2.11.2 and i get an error when i do this.

Comment: So far it sounds like to protected from direct new, you need to write the companion object yourself. Only when i do this it works as expected.

Comment: @MaatDeamon - Edited my answer to show that it is correct for 2.11.2.

Comment: That is really strange, i have the same result as you in my RELP. However when i compile with intellij or sbt i don't get that.

Comment: when i type about here is what i get:[info] This is sbt 0.13.5
[info] The current project is {file:XXXXXX}ocean 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.2
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4

Comment: is it ok that scala.2.10.4 is used for sbt, the plugins and the build definition, if not how may i change that ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon - You get the same behavior under 2.10, so that shouldn't make a difference.  Beyond that, I'm not an expert in debugging various problems that show up in SBT or various IDEs.  Do make sure you try the exact same code, though.  Easily-overlooked differences (e.g. using `()` or not) matter.

Comment: I just tried out of intellij simply using sbt in the command line and it does not work. So i think either it is a bug, or something special is happening when you are in the RELP.

Comment: It's some kind of bug on res1. X() is rewritten to new X in refchks; it works in REPL on separate lines because access is widened. It fails correctly with classdef and X() on same line (in one wrapping REPL object).